# Azure UDP Sockets Limitations?

Tags: c#, sockets, azure, console, azure-webjobs

So I'm trying to get a scheduled job running using Azure WebJobs.  In this case I'm sending a UDP message to 10,000+ servers and getting back a UDP response from them.

This works great on my local machine, but when I kick it off in Azure the first thousand or so requests go through, but then I can't open any more sockets as I get the following error:

```
 Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 208.64.200.52:27011
[05/17/2015 22:44:38 > 01cb94: ERR ]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
[05/17/2015 22:44:38 > 01cb94: ERR ]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
[05/17/2015 22:44:38 > 01cb94: ERR ]    at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient.Connect(IPEndPoint endPoint)
```

I'm not opening more than about 10 sockets at once here, what Azure rule am I breaking here?

Comment: Any reasons for the down votes?

Comment: What is the Tier you're running the WebJob on? Did you try a higher tier (Basic/Standard/Premium?)?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually swapped over to a VM, there also appears to be a hard limit on total bandwidth utilized -- though I can't seem to find where that's listed.